# Operation between hours

Tags: iphone

I have 2 buttons, when I click each button a timepicker comes out and return the time in the button. I have 2 text field and 1 label. In textfield 1 I put a number that will be subtracted to the difference between the time in button 1 minus the time in button 2.

My second text field will have a number that I will multiply by the results of the subtraction. I also have a label that will return the result. For Example:

in button 1 I have 6:00pm
in button 2 I have 8:30pm
subtracting them the results is 2.5 hours
in text field 1 I have 30 minutes
subtracting 30 minutes to 2.5hours will be 2 hours
in text field 2 I have number 3
multiplying number 3 to 2 hours I will have 6.
I would like to return 6 in the label

I could solve the part where I have the date picker returning the time.

Can anyone give me some suggestion how to solve the second part?
Thank you!

Comment: -1 Subject does not describe the question.

Comment: -1 needs rewriting to make it much much easier to read.

Comment: The question, as written, is not easily readable or understandable. Can you rephrase it to be more clear? A picture may help. Also: can you tell us what the end result should be? It may be that you are stuck because there is a better, easier solution out there. (Grammar nitpick: it's "label", not "lablel".)

Comment: @Cajun English nitpick: That's spelling, not grammar :P

Comment: @Yi I tend to perceive spelling as a subset and a component of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Create NSDate objects that have the same date part, but with the time set to the times in the buttons.

To subtract dates, use

```
 NSTimeInterval seconds = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:otherDate];
```

NSTimeInterval is just a number, you can multiply it.  First multiply by `60*60` to get it to hours.  Then multiply it by the number on your multiplier button.