# how do I get the number hours between two times?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operation between hours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235635/operation-between-hours)

I have 2 buttons if you press each one will come out time picker and return the time chosen in the button. How do I subtract the two times?
I try to explain it with and example:
I press button one, and I have time picker coming out, I choose lets say 6:00pm. 6:00pm will return in my button1.
I do the same thing with button two. I choose a time lets say 8:00pm. 8:00pm will return in my button2.
I would like to know how can I subtract them to find how many hours I have between button1 and button2. In this case would be 2 hours.

Here is a piece of code where I press the done button to return the time chosen in the button.

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed2:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerViewController2:didChooseDate:)]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];

        [self.delegate datePickerViewController2:self didChooseDate:dateString];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];      
    }
```

I believe I have to use this to have what I want:

```
//NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [firstTime timeIntervalSinceDate:secondTime];
```

but I am not quite sure how to use it.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This question is hardly better than your last one.  Please try writing clearly, using paragraphs, with code examples.  Explain what you have tried, what documentation you are using, and please try to use standard terminology if you know it.

Comment: Please provide some code sample.

Comment: Alex is right, please give us a clear question with code examples...

Comment: sorry guys, I am very new in programming and english is not my first language...I am Italian living in US. I promise I will improve my communication skills

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a UIDatePicker set to mode `UIDatePickerModeTime` then:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [dateFromButton1 timeIntervalSinceDate:dateFromButton2];
```

will give you the time difference in seconds: see the documentation for [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSinceDate_) and [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69) (which is defined as a double).

Comment: Thank you very much Nick.  - (IBAction)doneButtonPressed2:(id)sender
{
 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerViewController2:didChooseDate:)]) {
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
  
  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];
  
  [self.delegate datePickerViewController2:self didChooseDate:dateString];
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  
  NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [firsttime timeIntervalSinceDate:secondtime];  
 }

Comment: the piece of code above is when you choose the time and you press done button the time returns in the button

Answer (score 0):

I think i got what you are asking for.
Let date1 be your first date from button1, date2 would be your second date from button2

```
double subtractedTimeInterval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
NSLog(@"The Time Interval Between two dates  : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:"%g"subtractedTimeInterval]);
```

If the date1 is earlier than date2, the return value is negative.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. how do I put date1 and date2. I passed my buttons into numbers...am I on the right track? -(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.button.tag = 100001;
 self.button2.tag = 100002;
 self.button3.tag = 100003;
 self.button4.tag = 100004;
 buttonPressed = -1;
 buttonPressed2 = -1;

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very familiar with what you just said...would you be able to explain it again...

Comment: Do you think it is possible for me to pass you my code? So probably it is easier to comunicate.

Comment: When you click button1 there will be a DatePicker shown. So now you have to pick a date from that Picker. If you select a date  a delegate pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:  will be called. In that delegate declare a NSDate and assign the date you selected. That date will be date1. Similarly for Date2.

Comment: I don't have such code. Is there any possibility to pass you my code, It a lot easier to communicate.

Comment: Do you mean this piece of code: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSLog(@"Date Picker. viewDidLoad");
 [super viewDidLoad];
 double days = 2.0f;
 datePicker.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0f * 60.0f * 24.0f * days];

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to do with your code. I have given all my suggestion.  What is viewDidLoad doing here. You need to get subtracted date value by means of any user input say clicking a button.

Comment: without looking the code is really difficult to explain + I am not a very expert programmer. thank you very much anyway!